# Close colorbox modal window by clicking anchor link within modal window?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have made an anchor link - I am trying to make it so that when I click this anchor link (contained within the colorbox modal window) it will close the colorbox.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.newWindow a').click(function(){
          alert('hello world'); // checking to be sure click function is being called
         $.fn.colorbox.close(); 
     });
 });
```

I would think this would work.. what could I be doing incorrectly?

The content loaded in the colorbox is a hidden div on the page, not an iframe.

**EDIT:** I don't know why it wasn't working. I have seen someone else's example and it was put together just as mine was. I noticed that when clicking on the transparent div to give the 'depth of field' with the colorbox the modal window will fade out/close. So I changed the code to:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.newWindow a').click(function(){
         $('#DOMWindowOverlay').click(); // click overlay div and close colorbox
     });
 });
```

Not really a fix - it's a workaround.. but it works!

Answer (score 2):

Kyle, that looks fine to me.  Make sure you are also canceling the default action of the anchor, by returning false in your event handler or using the preventDefault method.  Ex:

```
 $('.newWindow a').click(function(){
     $.colorbox.close();
     return false;
 });
```

It's ok to use `.fn`, (it is the standard way to access a jQuery plugin's methods), but it isn't required for any of colorbox's.

Comment: Jack! The man! Adding your Colorbox has seriously improved how good my work looks.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What is that `.fn` for?

Try

```
$.colorbox.close()
```

Comment: Gave that a try and still no dice. Immediately came up with an answer though afterwards. So strange how putting it up here made me think about the problem differently.

Comment: Nice, I think your solution should work anyways. Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/uqnz9/

Comment: Weird.. I guess something on the page was interfering with it closing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because the link doesn't exist when the docReady is run.  In the future, you can do one of 2 things: A) put your click handler in a jquery live() function (still in docReady), or B) use colorbox's onComplete option to create the click handler (placed in the object literal you send when you create the colorbox).

Also, as Thorsten pointed out, the .fn part is not necessary because the author of colorbox had the foresight to create a link to $.colorbox.

Comment: Is your first statement right?  The question author said "The content loaded in the colorbox is a hidden div on the page, not an iframe" which would imply that the link is on the page with the ColorBox call in it.

Comment: @Kevin M: Thanks Kevin, I missed that. Of course you are correct, if it's already in the page then docReady will get it.  Also, I just ran a quick test with the original code (at the very top of the post) and got the link to close the colorbox with no problem. If kyle checks back maybe he could give us more info or say what was mixed up?

Answer (score 0):

Just put anchor `onclick="$('#registerDialog').dialog('close');">`

Where `registerDialog` is the modal dialog id like here `data_dialog_id`

```
@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", null, 
    new { @class = "openDialog",
          data_dialog_id = "**registerDialog**", 
          data_dialog_title = "btewary.blogspot.in" })
```